# Refreshing same browser window from windows run command

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsp

I have one web application. When client enters the address and after successfully logging in. He gets the home page with some data over the page. Now when any third party tool or from run command if i give the same url on which the client is with changed parameter values, i want the same browser window to be refreshed with updated/changed values without opening the new browser window. 
Whats happening now is that when i'm triggering the url from different source, its opening in new browser window. Plz help me out with few suggestions. 
Ars.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be for the web application to poll the server and refresh itself when there is an update.

Your command line tool can then contact the server and update the parameters directly, and the application in the user's browser will pick up those changes automatically.

Attaching to a running Internet Explorer instance is also possible, for example see this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9683/Automating-Internet-Explorer, or the Selenium project at http://seleniumhq.org/. But you're almost certainly going to make it easier for yourself by changing your application to refresh automatically.

Comment: Thakns Dan, but when i issue the address of the page from command line with some parameters then it'll open a new browser window, How to control that action?

Comment: I meant instead of opening the page with `iexplore url`, you should use `curl update_url?new_parameters` to update the parameters on the server and the page should refresh itself automatically. If you want to always bring the browser window into focus or to open a new browser when the user doesn't have the page already open, you'll have to use a COM-based IE driver like the one in the CodeProject article I linked to.